# System Memory keeps increasing in deep learning using pytorch & pytorch lighning (kaggle kernel)

Tags: memory, deep-learning, pytorch, kaggle, pytorch-lightning

My kaggle kernel's system memory just keeps growing during GPU training and I can't find where the problem is.

Log information on Wandb shows that System Memory keeps going up and finally reaches the point to cut everything off:

[wandb info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8Bfg.png)

I think there could be something wrong in the dataset or the training/valiation steps that caused the memory keeps going up as the training goes on according to Wandb information. But I can't find reason why (after thorough look up and comparison).

Here are my source code related to data training process from [kaggle - G2Net pytorch lightning EfficientNet](https://www.kaggle.com/hzhaobang/g2net-pytorch-lightning-efficientnet):

Dataset:

```
class BaseDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, df, transform=None):
        self.df = df
        self.file_names = df['path'].values
        self.labels = df[CFG.target_col].values
        self.wave_transform = CQT1992v2(**CFG.qtransform_params)
        self.transform = transform # image transform
        
    def apply_qtransform(self, waves):
        waves = np.hstack(waves) # 1D data array
        waves = waves / np.max(waves) # normalization
        waves = torch.from_numpy(waves).float()
       
        image = self.wave_transform(waves) # [1, 46, 385]
        
        return image
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx): # always idx
        # Load data.
        file_path = self.file_names[idx]
        waves = np.load(file_path)
        
        # Wave2Image transformation applied.
        image = self.apply_qtransform(waves)
        image = image.squeeze().numpy() # [46, 385]
        
        # Image transformation.
        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image=image)['image'] # [1, 46, 385]
            
        label = torch.tensor(self.labels[idx]).float()
        
        return image, label
        
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.file_names)
```

DataModule:

```
class G2NetDataModule(pl.LightningDataModule):
    def __init__(self, df: pd.DataFrame, fold: int = 0):
        super().__init__()
        self.df = df
        self.fold = fold
       
    def setup(self):
        train_idxs = self.df[self.df['fold'] != self.fold].index
        valid_idxs = self.df[self.df['fold'] == self.fold].index
        
        train_fold = self.df.loc[train_idxs].reset_index(drop=True)
        valid_fold = self.df.loc[valid_idxs].reset_index(drop=True)
        
        self.train_dataset = BaseDataset(train_fold, transform=get_train_transforms())
        self.valid_dataset = BaseDataset(valid_fold, transform=get_valid_transforms())
        self.test_dataset = BaseDataset(test_df, transform=get_test_transforms())
        
    def train_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(self.train_dataset,
                          batch_size=CFG.batch_size,
                          shuffle=True,
                          num_workers=CFG.num_workers,
                          pin_memory=True)
    
    def val_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(self.valid_dataset,
                          batch_size=CFG.batch_size,
                          shuffle=False,
                          num_workers=CFG.num_workers,
                          pin_memory=True)
    
    def test_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(self.test_dataset,
                          batch_size=CFG.batch_size,
                          shuffle=False,
                          num_workers=CFG.num_workers,
                          pin_memory=True)
```

LightningModule:

```
class G2NetLightningModule(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, pretrained=True):
        super().__init__()
        # Set model. Output: [48, 1], 48 for batches, 1 for output.
        self.model = timm.create_model(CFG.model_name, pretrained=pretrained, in_chans=1)
        n_features = self.model.classifier.in_features
        self.model.classifier = nn.Linear(n_features, CFG.target_size)
        
        # Set loss function.
        self.criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
    
    def forward(self, x):
        output = self.model(x)
        return output
    
    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):        
        x, y = batch # [C, H, W], [labels] from dataloader.
        y_preds = self.model(x).view(-1) # Reduce one dimension.
        loss = self.criterion(y_preds, y)
        score = roc_auc_score(y.cpu().numpy(), y_preds.sigmoid().detach().cpu().numpy())
        
        # Log score and loss for each step (batch).
        self.log('train_auc_step', score, on_step=True, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
        self.log('train_loss_step', loss, on_step=True, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
        
        return dict(loss=loss, predictions=y_preds, labels=y)
    
    def training_epoch_end(self, outputs):
        """Compute and log epoch roc-auc score.
        """
        preds = []
        labels = []
        
        for output in outputs:
            preds += output['predictions']
            labels += output['labels']
            
        preds = torch.stack(preds)
        labels = torch.stack(labels)
        
        train_epoch_auc = roc_auc_score(labels.cpu().numpy(), preds.sigmoid().detach().cpu().numpy())
        self.log('train_auc_epoch', train_epoch_auc, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
        
    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, y = batch
        y_preds = self.model(x).view(-1)
        loss = self.criterion(y_preds, y)
        
        self.log('val_loss', loss, prog_bar=True, logger=True) # Unable for step log.
        
        return dict(predictions=y_preds, labels=y)
    
    def validation_epoch_end(self, outputs):
        """Compute and log epoch roc-auc score.
        """
        preds = []
        labels = []
        
        for output in outputs:
            preds += output['predictions']
            labels += output['labels']
            
        preds = torch.stack(preds)
        labels = torch.stack(labels)
        
        val_epoch_auc = roc_auc_score(labels.cpu().numpy(), preds.sigmoid().detach().cpu().numpy())
        self.log('val_auc_epoch', val_epoch_auc, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
    
    def configure_optimizers(self):
        # Optimizer.
        optimizer = Adam(self.model.parameters(), lr=CFG.lr, weight_decay=CFG.weight_decay)
        
        # Scheduler.
        if CFG.scheduler == 'ReduceLROnPlateau':
            scheduler = ReduceLROnPlateau(optimizer, 
                                          mode='min', 
                                          factor=CFG.factor, 
                                          patience=CFG.patience, 
                                          verbose=True, 
                                          eps=CFG.eps)
        elif CFG.scheduler == 'CosineAnnealingLR':
            scheduler = CosineAnnealingLR(optimizer, 
                                          T_max=CFG.T_max, 
                                          eta_min=CFG.min_lr, 
                                          last_epoch=-1)
        elif CFG.scheduler == 'CosineAnnealingWarmRestarts':
            scheduler = CosineAnnealingWarmRestarts(optimizer, 
                                                    T_0=CFG.T_0, 
                                                    T_mult=1,
                                                    eta_min=CFG.min_lr ,
                                                    last_epoch=-1)
        
        return dict(optimizer=optimizer,
                    lr_scheduler=scheduler)
```

Train Loop:

```
# Initialize model.
model = G2NetLightningModule()

for fold in range(CFG.n_fold):
    if fold > 0: break # Debug and Parameter optimization before model selection.
    
    # DataModule.
    data_module = G2NetDataModule(train_df, fold)
    data_module.setup() # Just to check dataset information by running setup.
    
    # Logger.
    wandb_logger = get_logger(fold)
    
    # Trainer.
    trainer = pl.Trainer(gpus=1,
                         precision=CFG.precision,
                         callbacks=[early_stop_callback,
                                    checkpoint_callback],
                         max_epochs=CFG.epochs,
                         logger=wandb_logger,
                         deterministic=True,
                         stochastic_weight_avg=True, # https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.05407
                         progress_bar_refresh_rate=1)
    
    # Let's go
    trainer.fit(model, data_module)
    
    print(f'===Fold-{fold} running successful===')
```

I'm rather new in pytorch and pytorch lightning so there may be something important that I miss or some problems I didn't notice. Truly Grateful if anyone has any clue for this problem and I will update quickly if more information needed.

System Environment: Kaggle Kernel - [Specifications here](https://www.kaggle.com/docs/notebooks#technical-specifications)

Comment: Code has to be in the question as text, not as external links.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Thanks for reminding. I have added source code related to dataset and training loop in texts.